# light weight maven dependency management gui tool

Tags: user-interface, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I know eclipse kinda gives you a GUI view of maven dependency and dependency hierarchy. Is there any other GUI tools I can easily just drop in my pom.xml file and it does the resolution and gives me a nice view of the dependency tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [this neat project](http://code.google.com/p/maven-overview-plugin/) that allows you to generate graphs for your dependencies.

Personally I use [IntelliJ](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/05/maven-dependencies-diagram/) to get diagrams of my dependencies, but that's because IntelliJ as my IDE.

If you're a CLI user and don't mind having to navigate in CLI, you can also use [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which also gives you a graph of your dependencies.

For more, check the link below.

---

**Resources:**

- [codehaus.org - Dependency Graphing](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Graphing)